# sort class objects data members greatest to least

Tags: c++

I have class called `Racecar`, and 40 `Racecar` objects are in a `vector` and each object has a data member named `myTotalPoints`.

After each race and points are awarded, I want to sort all of the objects' `myTotalPoints` data members from greatest to least so I can show them in point standings. Does anyone know how I could sort all 40 of the `Racecar` objects' data members ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) to solve this problem.

Implement a binary function to be the second parameter in the `sort` function,
and in the binary function return the value basing on the comparison between the values of `myTotalPoints` in two `Racecar` Objects.

As the instruction goes, `comp` is:

> Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments,
>   and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates
>   whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go
>   before the second in the specific strict weak ordering it defines. The
>   function shall not modify any of its arguments. This can either be a
>   function pointer or a function object.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and most concise way is using [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a [C++11 lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7627098/78845):

```
std::sort(std::begin(racecars), std::end(racecars),
    [](Racecar const& a, Racecar const& b) {
    return b.myTotalPoints < a.myTotalPoints;   
    });
```

[See an example run](http://ideone.com/hFlPaO)!

Comment: @r.v he's already comparing the right-hand side to the left so it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort your vector in reverse order, use the reverse iterators.

```
std::sort(racecars.rbegin(), racecars.rend());
```

This will work if you have overloaded `operator<`.

```
struct Racecar {
    int totalPoints;
    friend bool operator<(const Racecar& left, const Racecar& right);
};

bool operator<(const Racecar& left, const Racecar& right) {
    return left.totalPoints < right.totalPoints;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Racecar> cars;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        cars.push_back(Racecar{i});
    std::random_shuffle(cars.begin(), cars.end());
    std::sort(cars.rbegin(), cars.rend());
}
```